# How to detect inside a method that another method in the same class has updated one of the classes variables?

Tags: java

(newbie-warning)

I have a class, MyClass, that implelements a listener interface (SomeListener). 
MyClass contains two counters, countA and countB. MyClass is added as a listener to some OtherClass. When something happens in OtherClass, it fires MyClass-methods incrementA or incremenetB.

MyClass also has a method myMethod that is called from ThirdClass. It then sends a list of requests to the server. The server responds to OtherClass for each of the requests. OtherClass then fires incrementA or incrementB.

My problem: I preferrably need myMethod to return only after the server has responded to OtherClass for all the requests. I can't seem to get this to work. This is a sketch of my code so far:

```
class MyClass implements SomeListener{

    private int counterA;
    private int counterB;
    private int numRequests;

    public boolean myMethod(){

        // send numRequests number of requests to a serve

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long end = start + 1000*numObjects;

        //wait for responses to all the requests, or timeout
        while(counterA+counterB < numRequests &&  currenttime<end){
            //wait... in a probably not so elegant fashion
        }

        if(counterA+counterB==numRequests){
            // do something
            return true
        }

        // timed out
        //do something else
        return false;
    }


    public void incrementA(){
        counterA++;
    }

    public void incrementB(){
        counterB++;
    }
}


class SomeListener{
    public void incrementA();
    public void incrementB();
}


class OtherClass{

    MyClass myClassObject = new myClassObject();

    //receives response from server and write to log

    if(response equals something)
        myClassObject.incrementA;
    else    
        myClassObject.incrementB;
}


class ThirdClass{

    MyClass myClassObject = new MyClassObject();
    if (myClassObject.myMethod()){
        // do something
    }
}
```

My problem is that myMethod doesn't register if counterA or counterB is incremented in the incrementA/B-methods. It runs to timeout all the time, even long after OtherClass has received the responses from the server. Could anyone show me the error of my ways?

Comment: Please post code that will compile and demonstrate the problem; a [mcve]. The code in the question will not compile, because in at least a couple of places you've referred to functions without calling them, written step-by-step code in the class body without an enclosing method, etc.

Comment: Fundamentally: Provided `incrementA` or `incrementB` is called by another thread while `myMethod` is running, `myMethod` will eventually see the change in value. If you make `counterA` and `counterB` `volatile`, you will make `myMethod` see those changes immediately.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I will upvote that if you write it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, new to StackExchange, will give runnable example next time :)

Thank you, making the counter volatile did the trick, it seems :) I was confused by that sometime the method actually noticed the changes to the counters, but most times it did not.

Answer (score 0):

With scenario you are in Concurrency Land. Move careful, its easy to hurt yourself.

One approach is to create a CountDownLatch and wait on it in `myMethod`,
then count down the latch in the `increment` methods. Note that this will only work when only one thread at atime might enter `myMethod`

See [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) for details how to use a it.